# DigitalOcean add domain to django instance with nginx and gunicorn

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn

I've setup the one click install django on digitalocean and added a domain to it. I'm also trying to add a sub domain before the site goes live. I've edited the nginx conf file as below

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html index.htm;

    client_max_body_size 4G;
    server_name beta.kazi-connect.com;

    keepalive_timeout 5;

    # Your Django project's media files - amend as required
    location /media  {
        alias /home/django/django_project/django_project/media;
    }

    # your Django project's static files - amend as required
    location /static {
        alias /home/django/django_project/django_project/static;
    }

    # Proxy the static assests for the Django Admin panel
    location /static/admin {
       alias /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/;
    }

    location / {
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_buffering off;

            proxy_pass http://app_server;
    }

}

upstream app_server {
    server unix:/home/django/gunicorn.socket fail_timeout=0;
}
```

and restarted both nginx and gunicorn however when I visit the sub domain I get a 502 bad gateway error.

Nginx log states there's an issue with gunicorn.

```
2017/01/24 16:24:19 [error] 6258#6258: *2 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 105.230.203.101, server: beta.kazi-connect.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/home/django/gunicorn.socket:/", host: "beta.kazi-connect.com"
2017/01/24 16:24:20 [error] 6258#6258: *2 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 105.230.203.101, server: beta.kazi-connect.com, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/home/django/gunicorn.socket:/favicon.ico", host: "beta.kazi-connect.com", referrer: "http://beta.kazi-connect.com/"
2017/01/24 16:24:22 [error] 6258#6258: *2 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 105.230.203.101, server: beta.kazi-connect.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/home/django/gunicorn.socket:/", host: "beta.kazi-connect.com"
2017/01/24 16:24:23 [error] 6258#6258: *2 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 105.230.203.101, server: beta.kazi-connect.com, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/home/django/gunicorn.socket:/favicon.ico", host: "beta.kazi-connect.com", referrer: "http://beta.kazi-connect.com/"
2017/01/24 16:25:00 [error] 6258#6258: *23 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 105.230.203.101, server: beta.kazi-connect.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/home/django/gunicorn.socket:/", host: "beta.kazi-connect.com"
2017/01/24 16:25:01 [error] 6258#6258: *23 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 105.230.203.101, server: beta.kazi-connect.com, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/home/django/gunicorn.socket:/favicon.ico", host: "beta.kazi-connect.com", referrer: "http://beta.kazi-connect.com/"
```

Comment: Seems like gunicorn is closing the connection unexpectedly. Is there anything in gunicorn error/access logs?

Comment: Problem was the `allowed_host = server_ip`

Answer (score 1):

Samuel's answer was right. The problem is that the domain names are not included in the ALLOWED_HOSTS. In the django_project/settings.py, search for the code below.

```
# Discover our IP address
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ip_addresses()
```

Add your domain name to ALLOWED_HOSTS, e.g.

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS.extend(["xyz.com"])
```